# JavaScript - Event listener for navigating through <select> options

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<select>` element with multiple options. Currently added event listener `change` for calling function. But it triggers only when the value is changed. I want to trigger ir while scrolling through the options as well. So I can see what each option does in real-time without actually selecting it. Tried setting event listener as `input` as well, but didn't work.

*Note: There are more than 1000 options inside select*

```
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
  <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
```

```
const dropdownSelect = document.querySelector("#dropdown");

function updateChanges() {
  console.log("Value changed");
};

dropdownSelect.addEventListener("change", updateChanges);
```

Comment: Short of creating your own dropdown UI I don't think you can. My reasoning is that the select UI is not actually in the page, and is rendered by the browser.

Comment: Browsers don't fire events while the user is looking through the options in a `<select>`, not even mouse events.

Comment: The only way is to abandon `<select>` and create a custom element yourself